# Incorrect tile loading with MapProxy

Tags: leaflet, mapproxy

I am trying to publish my WMS map that I created from GeoServer with Leaflet using MapProxy. But what could be wrong with the MapProxy and Leaflet are not the same?

[image: appearing in MapProxy]

[image: FAULT appearing in Leaflet]

```
services:
  demo:
  tms:
    use_grid_names: true
    # origin for /tiles service
    origin: 'sw'
  kml:
      use_grid_names: true
  wmts:
  wms:
    md:
      title: MapProxy WMS Proxy
      abstract: This is a minimal MapProxy example.

layers:
  - name: osm3122
    title: Omniscale OSM WMS - osm.omniscale.net
    sources: [osm_cache]

caches:
  osm_cache:
    grids: [webmercator]
    sources: [osm_wms]

sources:
  osm_wms:
    type: wms
    req:
      url: http://localhost:8080/geoserver/cite/wms?
      layers: cite:dunya
      grid: webmercator

grids:
    webmercator:
        srs: EPSG:900913
        origin: nw

globals:
```

Leaflet code:

```
  var a =  L.tileLayer('http://localhost:8011/tms/1.0.0/osm3122/webmercator/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
         transparent: true,
         attribution: "",
         tiled:true
    }).addTo(map);
```

Comment: Since there is string `tms` present in the layer address, I suppose it's TMS layer, so you should specify layer `tms` option: `tms: true`.

Comment: I did what you said but nothing changed, thanks for your reply

Comment: Then compare working and non working tile requests. Also, is working OpenLayers client code accessible? Having a look at it would reveal what goes wrong in Leaflet.